# Vue JS Validating Token

Tags: vue.js, django-rest-framework, djoser

i am learning web development, i have some question about Token validation for authentication systems to understand mentality and motivation.

1. Is there any performance issue if i check auth token is valid or not
   before navigating between routes?
2. What is the best and secure way to validate your cookies(auth tokens) with your request to your backend(rest framework) any issues please check following example scenario?

Scenario; you have basic django-djoser token authentication system. So, users login your website with auth token and you keep their auth token in cookie but anyone can create auth token in browser side so you have to validate their token before they are surfing on your great website. What is the best way to validate this tokens? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Covering your first answer, performance impact depends on what operations you will be doing to check|authenticate. It should not be that performant demanding for just a verification checkup. But this is dependent on your architecture. I'd advise you to use jwt or store your token in cache to avoid hitting your db just for each view authentication.

Tackling the second one, In DRF, I'll speak of two ways to approach your scenario,

1. Using custom authentication scheme:
   Here, you will override the BaseAuthentication class and create your own authentication mechanism. This has to return a user and auth(which is okay to be None). For more information, [check out here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#custom-authentication)
2. Using Permissions:
   In permissions, a view will not be executed until the permission is granted. In this permission class that you'll write, you will have to override the BasePermission class. In it override the has_permission method to return a boolean that either allows or rejects a user from checking into a view. For more [tap here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/).